# How do you remove a page

Tags: structure

How do you remove a page from the website?

Comment: There's some many ways to "add a page", that the answer is "it depends". We gonna need more information to help. Please, update your question.

Answer (score 2):

If you are talking about templates of EE, it is only deleted permanently from backend.

1. Go to **Design > Templates > Template Manager**.
2. Select group you want to delete file from.
3. Click on delete button right side of templates (Delete once can never undone.)

[image]